# RecyclerView: Profile Pics repeating/duplicating when scrolling up/down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently creating a recyclerView that shows a list of people with pics and other info. The texts info are showing correctly. Only the image or should I say the profile pics are sometimes duplicating/repeating when I quickly scroll up/down on the lists while it's still fetching pics from the server. I was looking for solutions however I can only find solutions that uses `Glide`. I'm currently using `CircleImageView` for my profile pics. Here's my onBindViewHolder code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MembershipActivationViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Member m = mMembers.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(m.getName());
    holder.email.setText(m.getEmail());
    if(m.getStatus().equals("Active")){
        holder.status.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#00CD00'>" + m.getStatus() + "</font>"));
    }else{
        holder.status.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>" + m.getStatus() + "</font>"));
    }
    holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(m.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
}
```

Comment: "however I can only find solutions that uses Glide" -- this problem can be handled by any serious image loading library. In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList), I use Picasso. Since you seem to know the solution... what is your specific question?

Comment: try setting the image to null at the beginning

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean that when I tried to look on the internet for solutions, I mostly see people using that Glide library or what not. However, I'm only using a simple CircleImageView. I'm don't really have a broad knowledge especially on Recycler View. So my question would be, what is the simplest solution to avoid repeating/duplicating images while scrolling, while using only simple coding like the one I posted above.

Comment: @MalekHijazi I tried putting `holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(null);` before  setImageUrl but still the same.

Comment: There is no solution "using only simple coding" that is simpler than using a library like Picasso. You are already using libraries, such as `recyclerview-v7`. A solution without such a library, taking into account threading, configuration changes, and caching, would require a few additional Java classes, in the low hundreds of lines of code, which I do not consider "only simple coding".

Answer (score 1):

Use Picasso library is highly recommended. Add the picasso library in your project then write your code some thing like this.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(m.getImageUrl()).into(imageLoader);
```

instead of this line

```
holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(m.getImageUrl(), imageLoader)
```

Comment: Is there a workaround without using Picasso library?

Comment: Yes. Follow this [link](http://blogs.innovationm.com/lazy-loading-and-memory-management-of-images-in-listview-in-android/). by following this tutorial you can done your job without library. I personally recommend to use Picasso or Android Query

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Glide over Picasso if you want to load profile images faster and occupy lesser disk space. The comparison of Glide and Picasso is made [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en). Also, I think it will solve your duplication problem.

To use Glide, write this line

```
Glide.with(context).load(m.getImageUrl()).into(holder.thumbnail);
```

instead of this

```
holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(m.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
```

Don't forget to add `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'`to your build.gradle

Comment: Yeah I was able to try it but still seeing duplicated images when scrolling down and also I noticed that images take more time to load.